# Why does `ofstream` miss some lines when writing to file?

Tags: c++, fstream, unicode-string

I have generated a bunch of UTF-16LE strings (3.8k+, `\n`-terminated) to write to a text file, still in UTF16. Somehow a part of these strings (~1.7k) are missing in the final file. The bug is not random, and the missing part is fixed no matter how I try to code the writing part.

Here is the code I used (slightly paraphrased):

```cpp
inline std::u16string str_u8_to_u16(const std::string & u8_str){
  return std::wstring_convert<
    std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t>{}.from_bytes(u8_str);
}

std::ofstream fout("output.txt", std::ios::trunc);
extern std::vector<std::pair<char16_t, std::size_t> > str_vec;

for (auto itr = str_vec.cbegin(); itr != str_vec.cend(); ++itr) {
  std::u16string line_to_write = std::u16string(1, itr->first) + u"\t"
                               + str_u8_to_u16(std::to_string(itr->second)) + u"\n";
                               // because the second term can be greater than 9
  // byte-by-byte write
  fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(line_to_write.c_str()),
             line_to_write.size() * 2);

  fout.flush();
}
```

I suppose inserting `flush()` into the loop would solve the problem, but no, the bug persists. I haven't tried `wchar_t` because I want to save memory, and I suppose these two shouldn't conflict.

Iʼm actually not sure whether Iʼm asking the right question, but I'm guessing it has something to do with my usage of `ofstream` and `char16_t`.

I even tried this:

```cpp
for (auto itr = str_vec.cbegin(); itr != str_vec.cend(); ++itr) {
  std::u16string line_to_write = std::u16string(1, itr->first) + u"\t" 
                               + str_u8_to_u16(std::to_string(itr->second)) + u"\n";
  auto end_before_write = fout.tellp();
  fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(line_to_write.c_str()),
             line_to_write.size() * 2);
  auto end_after_write = fout.tellp();
  std::cerr << std::dec << "end_before_write = " << end_before_write
            << ", end_after_write = " << end_after_write
            << ", diff = " << end_after_write - end_before_write << std::endl;
  fout.flush();
}
```

And the result is even more confusing: the difference of two `tellp()`s is never zero and actually looks perfectly normal. So where do the contents go? They can't just disappear into oblivion.

In case that matters, I'm on macOS 10.14.5 using gcc version 9.1.0 (Homebrew GCC 9.1.0).

Comment: What is `fout` type? In my opinion problem is connected to your cast to `const char*`, but without minimal, working example it might be harder to diagnose, that neccesary.

Comment: Note that codecvt_utf8_utf16 and wstring_convert are deprecated since C++17.

Comment: So is it complete lines that are missing from the final file, or just part of a line?

Comment: Don't forget that the bug may not be in the writing of the file, but in whatever way you are reading the contents of the file and determining that parts are missing. How is the size of the file (according to O/S), does that seem correct?

Comment: Do the missing strings have anything in common that sets them apart from the non-missing strings?

Comment: Presumably, `line_to_write.size() * 2` is the number of bytes to write... do any of your strings contain "odd" Unicode code-points that would necessitate the use of surrogate pairs, and hence more than "twice the length of the string" bytes?

Comment: Please explain what `fout` is, and please write down what you are expecting, plus what you actually get. Otherwise the code seems somewhat fine... By the way, why are you using the `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @RadosławCybulski @jan.sende fout is of plain `ofstream` type. I have added that in question description. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How do you check, if lines are missing? Because most linux tools won't work that well with utf16.

Comment: @john it's complete lines missing. I determined they are missing because I opened the result using sublime text and found only ~2.1k lines, instead of what `str_vec.size()` reports (~3.8k).

Comment: @RadosławCybulski I'm on macOS and I used Sublime Text. See above.

Comment: @jan.sende I'm using `reinterpret_cast` to get `char*` type so that `ofstream.write()` can accept it; I'm supposing I have to do the writing byte by byte, as `<<` operator of neither `ofstream` or `wofstream` accepts `char16_t`.

Comment: @TripeHound Actually a good part of these lines would include very strange code points (I'm dealing with some digitized ancient Chinese glyphs, which are probably non-standard), but I'm really not sure if there's any of them that needs more than two bytes for one glyph. I suppose UTF-16 just needs two bytes for all glyphs?

Comment: @VirgilMing No, UTF-16 uses two or four bytes for all glyphs, read up on surrogate pairs.

Comment: @VirgilMing As per [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) some code-points need two 16-bit numbers to represent them. Whether that _is_ the problem may depend on how the encoding happens, and whether `.size()` returns the number of characters/code-points, or the number of words needed to encode those points (I don't know enough to say one way or the other... just highlighting a possibility).

Comment: @molbdnilo I have yet to find what you asked; if anything, they all rest in relatively latter part and are largely contiguous.

Comment: @VirgilMing Hmm... I understand... I'm not sure if this is the right approach... Thanks for adding the `ofstream`. However, you should open the file with `std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary` or am I wrong? Plus... Try the loop without writing to file, but counting the entries which would be written. Is it the right number?